# Laptop refuses to recognize Optical Bay Hard Drive Caddy

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, bios, osx-yosemite

I've gone through several of these caddys.

My laptop (a Lenovo G500) continually has the same problem; it refuses to recognize the HD I connect to it using an Optical Bay Caddy I purchased on eBay (I've tried several, it does this with all of them). The first time I connected it it saw the Hard Drive and worked perfectly. I rebooted and it hasn't shown up in the BIOS's Boot Screen or anywhere else since.

Here are some pictures of the caddy itself: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL97J.jpg

Related BIOS configuration screens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg28V.jpg

Laptop specs:

> System: Lenovo G500 CPU: Intel Core i3-3120M CPU @ 2.50GHz Dual-Core
>
> Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, 1366 x 768

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same caddy model, it has the "same" issue. Have you tried restarting twice ? I don't know why, but every time I restart my laptop the hdd/ssd is not recognised, and after I restart the laptop, it's there again, seen and working without a problem( oh, and this is not random, every restart it happens again ). A simple "solution" would be to avoid restarting completely, use sleep or shutdown only... Sorry, but I don't think you will get any real solution any time soon.